# Connecting Access db in Visual C# express

Tags: c#, database, express, ms-access-2010

Is there any limitations in what can connect with what? I have a big problem in connecting my db file in visual C# express, I always get "The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine." error when I test my connection. I have win 7 with ms access 2010 and access database engine, all 64-bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the [Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=23734).  Even though it says it is for Office 2007 it works with 2010 also.  After you install that from there you should be able to just add a datasource within Visual Studio.

Comment: Its working. But i don't understand, I have installed DCC just for 64bit, and now when I have installed this 32bit version it worked!

Comment: @Nenad I do not know why this was happening.  I had this problem about 8 months ago and remember that almost everyone that was running x64 everything solved it with x86 install.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you just run your project under x86 configuration that error will be removed